# How fix Docker "command not found", "Object not found" and term "not recognised as part of cmdlet" errors

Tags: powershell, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

I have setup docker destop on my pc. I have run the simple "Whalesay" container to ensure everything is working. I then tried using the following pull and run command:

```
docker pull natverse/r-natverse
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8787:8787 \
-e DISABLE_AUTH=true \
-v "$HOME":/home/rstudio \
natverse/r-natverse
```

this comes from the "Natverse" available from docker hub at https://hub.docker.com/r/natverse/r-natverse

after what appears to be a succesful download of the container itself, I run into difficulties trying to run it, with the following error messages:

```
-e : The term '-e' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:1
+ -e DISABLE_AUTH=true \
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-e:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-v : The term '-v' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:4 char:2
+  -v "$HOME":/home/rstudio \
+  ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-v:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

natverse/r-natverse : The term 'natverse/r-natverse' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:5 char:2
+  natverse/r-natverse
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (natverse/r-natverse:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have tried uninstalling docker desktop and reinstalling the most up-to-date version, I have restarted my computer. I have also made sure I do not have docker toolbox installed. I am neither very experienced with docker nor am I a particularly technical person. I would massively appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Comment: May I suggest just installing this software natively? Docker on Windows has non-trivial performance and usability implications.

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape the newlines to expand command in multiple lines, use stop parsing symbol and  try this:

```
& docker.exe --% pull natverse/r-natverse
& docker.exe --% run -p 127.0.0.1:8787:8787 -e DISABLE_AUTH=true -v "$HOME":/home/rstudio natverse/r-natverse
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. When I entered this I received the following error: `docker: Error response from daemon: create $HOME: "$HOME" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.` Have I missed something? thanks again.

Comment: Hmm... try `/${home}`

Comment: Brilliant, that worked -- however, I am not sure if it related but when I try to start the container I get: `Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8787: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.` Are you familliar with this issue?

Comment: You also need to forward port 8787of your Docker machine to that host. Maybe if you are using a VM then it is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used `run -p 127.0.0.1:8787:8787`,  as you recommended in your answer. As I understand it,  the "-p" option should have taken care of forwarding the 8787 port to the host? I am not sure what else needs doing to get it to work. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Sorry, but we are getting out of capability for this question. Please consult opening a new thread here. Thank you